# Xcode/ Printing dot

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I am trying to print "." when I press on a button that shows "."

Basically I wanna grab "." on NSString format

So if I do

> NSString *dec = [sender currentTitle];

it just crashes when I try to run.

Comment: Your question is not clear.  Can you rephrase it, or give a more complete example of what you're attempting?

Comment: So my question is On the UI I want to make one button that has dot on it, and when I press that button, I wanna show that dot on label in UI. So if it was like java I wanna do something like

Comment: and I am going to append this variable dot on the print statement

Comment: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[sender currentTitle]]; print this value and check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Cocoa, all controls send notifications that they have been operated, by using a target-action mechanism.  The 'target' is any other object and the 'action' is any selector that that object responds to.  Buttons are no different.

So you can, for example, define:

```
-(void)buttonClicked:(id)sender {
  NSLog(@"Button was clicked!");
}
```

You'd hook that up to the button's target-action, by invoking `-setTarget:` and `-setAction:` accordingly.  The target will be `self`, if you're doing this from inside the class that handles the action:

```
[button setTarget:self];
[button setAction:@selector(buttonClicked:)]
```

Now when the button is pressed, you'll get a NSLog() output in the console.

To update the value of a label instead of printing something with NSLog(), you can probably figure that out, but:

```
-(void)buttonClicked:(id)sender {
  [label setText:@"."];
}
```

You should read Apple's documentation, which covers this stuff in great detail.

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CommunicatingWithObjects/CommunicateWithObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002974-CH7-SW14

PS: stackoverflow is for all programming languages, so make sure to tag your questions with the relevant programming language.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! This was my very first question on stackoverflow and I did not know anything about this at all :P What you explained me makes a lot of sense. Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
 UIButton *resultButton = (UIButton *)sender;
 NSString *dec = resultButton.currentTitle;
```

Comment: Thank you! :) Your answer was also very helpful but I can only choose one

Comment: Its Ok :) we are not having an election here :P

Answer (score 0):

Try Something like this

```
 NSString *strdec = [sender titleLabel].text;
```